# ¿Cómo evitar carga de archivo .htaccess en laravel y git?

Tags: laravel, git, .htaccess

Tengo mi archivo gitignore así:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/public/.htaccess
.env
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
```

Cómo ven, no quiero que se suba el archivo .htaccess que está en la carpeta public, más sin embargo al hacer

```
git add .
git commit -m ""
git push origin master
```

Vuelve a reescribir el archivo .htaccess.

**¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que no se suba el archivo .htaccess?**

Gracias

Comment: ¿El fichero /public/.htaccess está ya en el repositorio? Si ya has commiteado previamente un fichero, .gitignore no lo va a ignorar. El fichero .gitignore solo sirve para ignorar ficheros que no existen aún en el repositorio. En caso de que este sea el problema, tendrás que hacer git rm del fichero (hazte una copia de seguridad por si acaso), commitear el borrado, y después el .gitignore te dejará ignorarlo.

Comment: Y también comprueba que el fichero se llame .gitignore (con punto delante) ya que en la pregunta mencionas gitignore sin punto.

Comment: ah okey yaya, entonces, borro el archivo .htaccess, subo mi archivo .gitignore con la excepción del .htaccess y despues vuelvo a cargar el archivo .htaccess, ¿cierto? y si, mi archivo si se llama .gitignore (sólo lo olvidé en el post) gracias.

Comment: Eso es, necesitas borrarlo para que lo pueda ignorar, una vez hagas commit, restaura el archivo, pero al hacer git add en principio no te debería añadir el fichero. Si te lo sigue añadiendo, avisa y vemos como podemos solucionarlo.

Comment: Se me olvidó comentar, funcionó perfecto, te agradezco @ordago